# How to set dynamic properties in Windows Custom Controls

Tags: c#, dynamic, custom-controls

I have created a user control, and  which is having two properties

1. Type
2. Parameter

where `Type`  is enumerations,

```
public enum Type { XType , YType }
```

and `Parameter` is of type `String`

Now,  i need to change the `Parameter` into enum. I'm sure that each `Type` will have two parameter .

which are `XTypeFoo, XTypeBar, YTypeFoo, YTypeBar`.

Prior, I've kept the `Parameter` as a `String` property. Now i have created two enum for this,

```
public enum XParameter { XTypeFoo, XTypeBar } and
public enum YParameter { YTypeFoo, YTypeBar }
```

Now i need to change the type of the `Parameter` property from `string` to something else ( depends upon the `Type`)

i.e if user selects `Type` as `XType` then `Parameter` should be of `XParameter` and if `YType` then `XParameter`.

So what will be base type.

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C# : " and such. That's what the tags are for.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible and I don't think it's needed. You should rather redesign your classes.

How about having an enum with just `{ Foo, Bar }` for Parameter?

Answer (score 0):

You can not inhert from `enums` so you need to use classes. Either use class constants or a "Dummyclass" for each enum-value:

In both cases you use a base class:

```
public class BaseParameter { }
```

"Dummyclass":

```
public class XParameter : BaseParameter { }
public class YParameter : BaseParameter { }
public class XTypeFoo : XParameter { }
public class XTypebar : XParameter { }
public class YTypeFoo : YParameter { }
public class YTypebar : YParameter { }
```

Constants:

```
public class XParameter : BaseParameter
{
    public readonly BaseParameter TypeFoo = new XParameter();
    public readonly BaseParameter TypeBar = new XParameter();
}
public class YParameter : BaseParameter
{
    public readonly BaseParameter TypeFoo = new YParameter();
    public readonly BaseParameter TypeBar = new YParameter();
}
```

Inboth cases you can use [`IsAssignable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.isassignablefrom.aspx) to check for `XParameter` or `YParamter` and for the exact you use `value is XTypeFoo` or `value == XParameter.TypeFoo`.

Answer (score 0):

If `Type` is going to be an enumeration and `Parameter` will also be an enumeration (albeit allowed values will depend on `Type`) then essentially, all possible values are known in advance. So why not have a single combined enumeration for `Parameter` and discard `Type` property? For example,

```
public enum ParameterType
{
  XTypeFoo,
  XTypeBar,
  YTypeFoo,
  YTypeBar,
}
```

Alternately, you can start asking `Parameter` about the type information. For example,

```
public interface IParameter
{
   public ParamType GetParamType();
}

public sealed class FooParameter : IParameter
{
  public static readonly FooParameter XParameter = new FooParameter();
  public static readonly FooParameter YParameter = new FooParameter();

  public ParamType GetParamType() { return ParamType.Foo; }

  private FooParameter() { }
}

public sealed class BarParameter : IParameter
{
  public static readonly BarParameter XParameter = new BarParameter();
  public static readonly BarParameter YParameter = new BarParameter();

  public ParamType GetParamType() { return ParamType.Bar; }

  private BarParameter() { }
}

public class MyControl : UserControl
{
   IParameter Parameter {get; set; }

   ...
}
```